# Help solving this GCSE question on angles/parallel lines/isoscelesh

Tags: triangles, angle

Problem:

$ABC$ is an isosceles triangle with angle $\angle ABC=52^\circ$.

$XY$ is parallel to $BC$.

Work out the size of angle $\angle BAC$.

[image: triangle]

Hi I need help solving this GCSE question under the topic 'angles in parallel lines'. The answer is $76$ but I don't know how you get that

Thanks

Jasmine

Comment: Sorry, should have added image description!

Comment: Since it's isosceles, I think you are supposed to assume from the picture that the angle at $B$ and the angle at $C$ are the same (though since it's not explicit, it's hard to tell). This would give an answer of $76^\circ$ rather than $72^\circ$ though.

Comment: Yes, this is not how you do it. :P thank you for your help

Comment: Well, assuming the isosceles part, then the only possible answers are $76^\circ$ or $64^\circ$. So either there is a typo in the question (i.e. it should have been $54^\circ$ instead of $52^\circ$) or a typo in the answer.

Comment: I see thanks Peter. the answer is actually 76 degrees! Very sorry

Comment: I think in addition to making assumptions which we shouldn't do this answer doesn't use the fact that there are parallel lines

Comment: yeah, the line $XY$ is just a distraction, it is completely unnecessary

Comment: I don't think so. It's mentioned in the question and is under the topic of angles in parallel lines. It doesn't make sense to be isosceles work here

Comment: I've emailed the book people they say they don't provide worked solutions, so I am thinking of telling them to inform the editors if there is something wrong with the q

Answer (score 0):

Here we assume $B=C$ so $52+52+x=180$ so $x=76$. Here $x=A$. But still i am not gettin why its given that $xy||BC$ whats its use.

Comment: This is why I believe the assumption bit is wrong. It's very unmathematical to be making assumptions like this, although it is GCSE, which is why shool maths frustrates me!

Comment: So which concepts do you think are to be applied any particular one ?? And i hardly think theres any use of angles in parallel lines.

Comment: Yes. You need to use corresponding/alternate angles. I don't know if you are not from the UK, but it is a part of the school syllabus here. I think I will just email the writers. Thank you